# Ошибка при запросе на wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Хочу выполнить данный SQL запрос, но он не выводит ничего.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'instafeed_setup_menu');

function instafeed_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Test Plugin Page', 'InstaFeed', 'manage_options', 'insta-feed', 'instafeed_admin_panel' );
}

function instafeed_admin_panel(){

    $fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM options");

    foreach ($fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft) {
        echo $fivesdraft->id;
    }
}
```

Код находится в главном файле плагина. Возможно на wordpress запросы выполняются по другому. Подскажите в чем ошибка и как мне выполнить данный запрос на wordpress ?

Comment: Ответ вам дали правильный, но в WP так не делают. Есть функции для считывания и обновления опций, которые хорошо кешируются. Почитайте про get_option() https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_option и связанную с ней update_option()

Comment: У вас точно таблица `options` без префикса в базе?

Comment: @tutankhamun скорее всего да. Посмотрите, как он обрабатывает данные из этой таблицы. Его код довольно бессмысленный для wp_options.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Согласен. Тогда получается функции `*_option()` автору вопроса не помогут

Comment: @tutankhamun я ему предложил не лазить в базу своими тормозными запросами, выкинуть вообще таблицу options, и использовать функции, как положено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас внутри функции `instafeed_admin_panel()` нет переменной `$wpdb`, поэтому ничего и не происходит. Не эксперт в `WP` но попробуйте добавить строчку `global $wpdb`, так:

```
function instafeed_admin_panel(){
    global $wpdb;
    $fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM options");

    foreach ($fivesdrafts as $fivesdraft) {
        echo $fivesdraft->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ответ правильный, дело именно в объявлении глобальной переменной.